# Build succeeds in VS2019, but fails on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I have a line of code which builds in VS2019... but fails when I try and build it using azure devops pipelines.

[image]

[image]

It was added by one of my team.

I actually thought this to be disallowed. I believe naming arguments must be applied, from the first named, to the last parameter?

But VS2019 allows it?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the visual designed or yaml? Can you post the pipeline?

Comment: I am using the predefined steps currently. It was simply a build of the solution that tripped it.

Comment: I see it myself. Thanks @Jabberwocky. I am using the wrong VS version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the YAML, I can see the VS version is incorrect.

Build YAML

```
  PublishProfile: 'VSORelease'

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution Retailer.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: Retailer.sln
    vsVersion: 14.0
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="$(PublishProfile)"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```